# Time of execution in Tensorflow higher than in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, gradient-descent

I'm reproducing a Gradient Descent example from Geron's Hands-On Machine Learning both with Tensorflow and Numpy. It's odd but even with GPU enabled, Numpy seems to be 5 to 6 times faster than Tensorflow.

I'm wondering about what am I doing wrong when setting up Tensorflow. Both codes are presented below:

First tensorflow. Running time: aprox. 8 seconds

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
dados = fetch_california_housing()
nlins, ncols = dados['data'].shape

minimos = np.min(dados['data'],axis=0)
maximos = np.max(dados['data'],axis=0)
intervalo = maximos - minimos
dados_n = (dados['data'] - minimos) / intervalo

import numpy as np
uns = np.ones(nlins).reshape(-1,1)
x = np.concatenate([uns, dados_n], axis=1)
y = dados['target'].reshape(-1,1)

eta = 0.1 
epocas = 10000 

import tensorflow as tf
X = tf.constant(x, dtype=tf.float32, name='X')
Y = tf.constant(y, dtype=tf.float32, name='Y')
beta = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([ncols + 1, 1],
                                     -1.0, 1.0,seed=42), name='beta')
Yhat = tf.matmul(X, beta, name='Yhat')
erro = Yhat - Y
mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(erro), name='mse')
gradiente = 2/nlins * tf.matmul(tf.transpose(X), erro)
novo_beta = tf.assign(beta, beta - eta * gradiente)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

from time import time

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(init)
inicio = time()
for i in range(epocas):
    sess.run(novo_beta)
fim = time()
result = mse.eval()
sess.close()

tempo = fim - inicio
print("Tempo = %.2f" % tempo)
print("MSE = %.2f" % result) # 0.57
```

Now numpy. Running time: 1.50 seconds

```
epocas = 10000
eta = 0.1

import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision=3)

from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
dados = fetch_california_housing()
nlins, ncols = dados['data'].shape
uns = np.ones(nlins).reshape(-1,1)

minimos = np.min(dados['data'],axis=0)
maximos = np.max(dados['data'],axis=0)
intervalo = maximos - minimos
dados_n = (dados['data'] - minimos)/intervalo

x = np.concatenate([uns,dados_n], axis=1)
y = dados['target'].reshape(-1,1)

np.random.seed(42)
beta = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=9).reshape(-1,1)

from time import time
inicio = time()
for i in range(epocas):
    mse = np.mean(np.square(x.dot(beta)-y))
    gradiente = 2/nlins * x.T.dot(x.dot(beta)-y)
    beta = beta - eta * gradiente
fim = time()
tempo = fim - inicio
print("tempo = %.2f" % tempo) 
print("mse = %.2f" % mse)
```

What am I doing wrong in the Tensorflow implementation?

Comment: How about larger dataset? Try 10x larger things may be different. Or may not, judging from your operation was fairly simple. Tensorflow needs to initialize context and placeholders first while you were only dealing with data in numpy.

Comment: If you look in the tensotflow code, I'm measuring just the time it takes to calculate the betas. The timing both starts and finishes inside the session. What you mention was my first tought but increasing the dataset just increased the total ammount of time it took to run. What I think is that I'm doing something wrong with the way I execute the operations, just don't know exactly what it is.

Comment: Interestingly, I ran your code in IPython without gpu enabled it only took ~2.5s to finish while the numpy version took ~1.6s. I think it is very likely that copying data to gpu took some time. Can you reproduce without gpu enabled? 8s is _significantly_ longer, that's unusual.

Comment: I did what you suggested (in Google Colab, because there you easily can turn on and off the gpu support). I think the GPU copying that you mention may be the culprit in this case. With GPU enabled: 5.0s. Without GPU: 4.5 seconds. Numpy: 2.8 seconds. Still faster by a large margin...